# Creating a webpage that regularly/automatically runs and displays output from an existing Python script?

Tags: python, web

I have written a Python script that, when executed, uses FTP to grab a file (a text file containing a Terminal Aerodome Forecast, e.g. ftp://tgftp.nws.noaa.gov/data/forecasts/taf/stations/KBOS.TXT), decode it, and generate a plot of the decoded data.

New forecasts are issued ~6 hours, and I want to create a webpage that updates automatically/regularly, showing the graphical representation of all of the forecasts issued over the last 48 hours (this will involve some archiving of the .TXT files because forecasts are only available going back 24 hours). I am comfortable with Python but am completely new to web scripting, and so I’m having some difficulty sorting through the abundance of information out there and figuring out the best place so start.

Comment: Do you have a framework in mind? It sounds like you want some sort of cron job.

Comment: This is a broad question with a huge variety of possible solutions.  One of the simplest solutions is to have your python running on your web server by regular cron and outputting an image file that is reference in a hard coded html web page.  I find it best to start with simple.. then work towards the more robust and complex solutions, depending on your needs.

Comment: Easiest solution is to have a directory where you store all the TXT files and a directory where you store/create PNG files. Create a static webpage that has some auto-refresh functionality to it and has a link to a PNG. You then run the processing script on a crontab job as often as you want. The script could optionally create a symbolic link named "latest_img.png" or something that points to the image you just created. Sound like something that would work for you?